# Expectation of a battery lifetime: Uniform Distributions

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, expected-value

Question:

A battery has a lifetime of $24$ hours and it is used for maximum three days. On each day, a person uses the battery for $K$ hours, where $K$ is uniform on $[0,24]$ and independent of the other days. What is the expectation of the remaining lifetime at the end of the third day?

My work:

Let $X$, $Y$, $Z$ as the amount of battery lifetime used on each day, respectively. Then the amount of battery lifetime left at the third day would be as follows:

$W=$ $[(24-X)/24]$ * $[(24-X-Y)/24]$ * $(24-X-Y-Z)$

Since at the second day, for a probability of $X/24$, the remaining lifetime would be $0$, and else (for a probability of $(24-X)/24$), there would be $(24-X-Y)$ left. I did the same for the third day.

Then I computed $E[W]$, which seemed to be $4$, but the correct answer seems to be $1$ (hour).

I think $W$ is miscalculated, because I checked the rest a couple times. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

---

(Edit) If it is simplified into a two-day process, I thought it can be calculated as the following:

Let $W$ the amount of lifetime left at the end of the second day. If $X$ is used on the first day, there is a $(X/24)$ probability that the battery will be used up on the second day. On the other hand, $((24-X)/24)$ is the probability that the used amount of the battery is $(X+Y)$, or $(24-X-Y)$ is the left amount.

Then $W=(X/24)*0+((24-X)/24)*(24-X-Y)$

and

$E[W]= (1/24) * E[(24-X)(24-X-Y)]= (1/24)*(24^2 - 48E[X] - 24E[Y] + E[X^2] + E[XY])$

where

$E[X]=E[Y], E[X^2]=E[XY]$ since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, and $E[X]=12, E[X^2]=192$.

Then we have:

$E[W]=24-2*12-12+16=4$ (hours),

which is the same as the calculation obtained by the integration method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you just want to integrate $24-x-y-z$ over the region where this is positive?  That is, $${1\over24^3}\int_0^{24}\int_0^{24-x}\int_0^{24-x-y}(24-x-y-z)dzdydx$$

Comment: Got it! Thanks for a straightforward answer. But can you tell which part I missed at my original solution?

Comment: @Richard Well, to get a uniform probability distribution over $[0,24]$, I have to divide by $24,$ so for a triple integral, I divide by $24^3$.  For the average use in a day, for example, we'd compute ${1\over24}\int_0^{24}xdx=12.$

Comment: @Richard All I can say about what's wrong is that you seem to be trying to accomplish by multiplication what you need to do by adjusting  the limits of integration.  Maybe I just don't understand what you're doing, but it simply looks wrong to me.  On second thought, maybe you're thinking about the probability that the battery isn't used up, but that's not how to compute the expectation.

Comment: Just to add, if I apply my method to a two-day example, not three as this question, it works... (The answer is same as the integral solution, or 4 hours.) The problem occurs when I try to extend it to a three-day process. / Now I saw your second comment - can you please tell why it is not right to use the probability the battery isn't used up?

Comment: @Richard.  Interesting ... I'll have to think about this.  I don't have an explanation yet.  Would you please edit the question to show the calculations for the two-day example?

Comment: Done editing, you may check. But as I edited the question, I think there was a mistake as I wrote $W$ as the equation above - to me, the term expressed as $W$ seems to be closer to $E[W]$ rather than $W$ (but I still can't tell exactly).

Answer (score 1):

Just an addendum to saulspatz's answer, in which for convenience I'll change time units to days so every $24$ becomes a $1$: if the battery is used for uniformly distributed time periods on each of $n$ days, the fraction of its lifetime remaining is $\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$, which in the $n=3$ case considered herein becomes $\frac{1}{24}$, i.e. an hour as required. But where did I get this formula from?

We wish to evaluate $\int_{P_n}(1-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)d^n x$, where $P_n$ is the region $x_i\ge 0,\,\sum_i x_i\le 1$. With the substitution $x_i=\sin^2 t_i\cdot \prod_{j<i}\cos^2 t_j$, the Jacobian is $2^n\prod_i \sin t_i \cos^{2n+1-2i}t_i$, and $1-\sum_i x_i=\prod_i\cos^2t_i$. The integral becomes $$2^n\prod_i\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin\theta\cos^{2n+3-2i}\theta d\theta=2^n\prod_i\frac{1}{2n+4-2i}=\prod_i\frac{1}{n+2-i}=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}.$$